# CGRectMake label doesn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrectmake

I've just started to make a new app with a navigation bar. I made the first view with the navigation in the `AppDelegate.m`.

AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    sleep(2);
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil]];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Then, I making the view of the HomeViewController inside `loadView` method.

LoadView of HomeViewController :

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.searchPoiInstructionsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
    self.searchPoiInstructionsLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.searchPoiInstructionsLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.searchPoiInstructionsLabel.text = @"HELLO WORLD";
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchPoiInstructionsLabel];
}
```

My label Hello World doesn't appear...

[image]

For the frame, if I set `CGRectMake(0, 65, 50, 20)` , `65` for `y`, my "Hello World" appears... (I know, I have to increase the width :) )

[image]

I just don't understand the origins of my view...  If someone can explain me please.

Thanks

Comment: I think adding your CGRectMake code in `viewWillAppear` method should fix your problem?

Comment: you could also do [self.searchPoiInstructionsLabel sizeToFit] to fix the width automatically. You'll need to have autolayout turned off if you're using storyboards though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is iOS7 baggage. If you run your app under iOS6, you will see the label as you expect/intend.

Under iOS7, your view originates under the navigation bar which is why you don't see the label when you set the frame to originate at 0,0. If you look really closely, you can actually see the blurred label behind the Carrier indicator in the status bar.

There are multiple ways to work with this:

If the `UINavigationBar` is not translucent, then the 0,0 origin will work.

You can update the labels frame using `topLayoutGuide`

You could use a `UIScrollView` instead of `UIView`

Comment: It's so annoying :/ ... It's really not practice to draw views if the behavior is different between platforms :( . 
Btw, I tried to put the `UINavigationBar.opaque = YES;`,the origin 0,0 still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, the property you need to set is `translucent`. `opaque` is a UIView property that has different functionality.

Comment: I did set `translucent` to `YES`. The problem is still here. My origin is still at the top of the window :/ , not at the bottom of the navigation bar.

Comment: `translucent` is `YES` by default. You need to set it to `NO` to make it not translucent.

Comment: It works !!!! Sorry, I didn't know that it was YES by default. 
It was long time ago that I haven't coded iOS app. Thanks for the tips ;)

Answer (score 0):

---

Origin in iOS 7 is kind of different. In a Navigation Controller, things below Navigation bar can be showed a little with blur effect. So the label's origin in the Navigation Controller is up-left (0, 0) point below the Navigation bar instead of the leftest point under the Navigation bar. Here a [demo](https://github.com/NjrSea/Frame-Demo) for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([[[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][0] intValue] >=7)    {
      if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you to take the time to answer to my issue @VineeshTP... I was still looking for solutions on internet. I was wondering that there is  probably another than that to draw my views. I mean... If it's possible to check the device version on every `viewDidLoad`, it would be so much better. For now, I just decided to have `iOS 7` as target... It seems to tricky to make the design for both targets... :/

Comment: Yeah, I just did set the navigation bar `translucent` to `YES`, and it made exactly what I want. I set it just one time in my appDelegate, and I don't have issues anymore with the origin of the view. But thank you for your concern, I really appreciate :)